# How to calculate impact metrics in the CVSS standard

Tags: security

I am trying to calculate impact metrics (confidentiality, availability and integrity) in the CVSS standard.

Can anyone suggest how this is done?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://security.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the definitions provided in the standard since you are following a standard to communicate the findings in a standardized and commonly-agreed way.
Refer to this document: https://www.first.org/cvss/specification-document

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a distinction between CVSS v2 and v3, so you would need to specify which one you use (one has 'complete' the other 'high' as possible impacts for CIA).

In any case, in order to assess the proper impact, you need to understand the vulnerability and the standard. The official standard has many different examples.

A couple here: assume you have a vulnerability that allows you to crash the Apache Web Server by sending a malformed request from remote. If we have to assign a CVSS score for the Web Server itself, Confidentiality would not be impacted as nothing is leaked, Integrity would not be impacted as no data is being manipulated. Availability however would be completely impacted, as the server would not respond anymore.

However, let's assume that we have to assign a CVSS for the same issue, only this time we do it for an operating system (e.g. the server itself on which the http server is running). While confidentiality and integrity still are not impacted, the availability of the server would be impacted only PARTIALLY. While the web server might not respond anymore, other services might (e.g. SSH, Mailserver, etc).

This was to make it clear, that CVSS cannot be calculated automatically, but has to be assessed for each vulnerability in relation to the affected software component. There are also a number of other pitfalls defined by the standard, so I strongly recommend you go read it!

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, your answer is really interesting. :)